# Ubuntu won't connect directly to wan

Tags: internet

so my internet provider has an option that allows me to have 2 wan ip addresses from their "router" and the setup works like that:

another router is connected to 1st port and almost everything else is connected to that either through cable or wifi.

My pc is connected to the 2nd port, so that I can host some games for my friends.

Lately I set myself up a "server" which is basically an old pc with some just good enough specs for its purpose and I got myself ubuntu in there.

Now when this server is connected to, let's call it, lan router, everything works fine, but when it's connected to directly to wan, it tries connecting for like a minute and then a little window pops up and says it's unable to connect.

I looked a bit into the ubuntu settings and it doesn't seem like I have any kind of firewall installed.

Answer (score 0):

You should double check your network topology and see if you are able to reach your gateway IP, if not double check that the LAN does actually allow ARP requests between those hosts and if they are able to gather MAC addresses of the GW and other hosts.

If you are not able to see any host via ARP you are most likely to be in a different LAN or separated network segment